# cudaMalloc3DArray fails with bad value -- limit to size?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Calling:

```
cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent( 1920 * sizeof(float), 1080, 10);
chanDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc ( 32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
err = cudaMalloc3DArray  ( &(devYAll[0]), &chanDesc, extent, 0);
```

is failing with `err=cudaErrorInvalidValue`.  When I use the first arguement to extent as 1024 or smaller then the call to 3D array succeeds.   Is there somehow a limit on the size of the memory that can be allocated with `cudaMalloc3DArray` ?

Comment: tried to make code indent codelike;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a limit on extent size - either 2048x2048x2048 or 4096x4096x4096 depending on which hardware you have (from the details in your question I presume you have a Fermi card). But that true source of your problem is your `make_cudaExtent` call. For `cudaMalloc3DArray`, the first argument of extent should be given in *elements*, not bytes. This is why you are getting an error for first dimensions > 1024, as 1024 * sizeof(float) = 4096  which is the limit of Fermi GPUs.

So to allocate a 1920x1080x10 3D array, do this:

```
cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent( 1920, 1080, 10);
chanDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc ( 32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
err = cudaMalloc3DArray  ( &(devYAll[0]), &chanDesc, extent, 0);
```

In this call, the size of the type is deduced from the channel description, and the extent dimensions are modified as required to meet the pitch/alignment requirements of the hardware.